# autocompletetextview as a hint

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to find a way to create autocompleteTextview as a edit-text hint. 
Can you please give me a good advice.

Here's an image
[image]

Comment: Have you set hint property to youe autocomplete TextView?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: No I didn't set a hint. I don't know how to do this

Comment: Sad that this question was closed. It is a good question, and is the only one of it's kind.